# Log a message when a regex pattern has been found or not (verbose re.sub)

Tags: python, regex, string

When replacing a text with `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = 'This is a sample123 text'
s = re.sub(r'sample\d+', 'another', s)
print(s)
```

**is there a built-in way to make `re.sub` verbose?** i.e. print:

- 'Pattern ... has been found and succesfully replaced'
- or 'Pattern ... not found'

I was about to roll my own function:

```
def mysub(r1, r2, s):
    if re.search(r1, s):  # note: don't use re.match: it matches from beginning only
        print('Pattern %s found' % r1)
        return re.sub(r1, r2, s)
    else:
        print('Pattern %s not found' % r1)
        return s
```

but I thought maybe it's possible out of the box.

Comment: Your solution is as straightforward as it gets. There is no built-in method that fits your exact requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the direct answer to your question is no. There is no "verbose" logging method in the `re` package that I am aware of. That said, [`re.subn()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn) is fairly useful here since it returns a count of substitutions made so you can avoid testing `re.search()` before calling `re.sub()`.

For example:

```
import re

regex = r'sample\d+'
sub = 'another'
text = 'This is sample123 text'
[new_text, count] = re.subn(regex, sub, text)

message = f'{regex} matched, {count} substitutions' if count else f'{regex} not found'

print(message)
print(new_text)
# OUTPUT
# sample\d+ matched, 1 substitutions
# This is another text
```